# Checkbox label id increment within ngrepeat.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="1"><label for="1"></label></div>
```

I want to style my checkbox, so there must be an id and a label, for the checkbox to work (to be checked or unchecked) properly.

I can set it using pure js, by incremental but that's not the angular js way. I'm putting it within ngrepeat, think of this like a todo list, how to make it incremental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the index part of ng-repeat, that is, the key:

```html
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="(index,value) in items">
   <input type="checkbox" id="{{index}}"><label for="{{index}}"></label>
</div>
```

or use the child scope `$index` value

```html
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
   <input type="checkbox" id="{{$index}}"><label for="{{$index}}"></label>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yh02rAuH40XU0hB4eQO6?p=preview

The difference between the two approaches is that you are assuming the scope `$index` suffices just for making the items ordinal. in the `key` approach you can actually access the original index on the items array (but you can also access it in `$scope.item`)

Comment: this work but I've tab for every set of todo list item. This work only for ONE set of item, but not in other set, nothing happen when I click on the checkbox of other set.

Comment: could you elaborate? I couldn't understand what you said, sorry

Comment: When you clarify, please do so on the main question for others to see as both my answer and @pocesar answer are quite similar

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index to find the index of the item in the array ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ALHUJ/))

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{$index}}"/>
<label for="{{$index}}">{{$index}}</label>
```

Comment: this work but I've tab for every set of todo list item. This work only for ONE set of item, but not in other set, nothing happen when I click on the checkbox of other set.